# Split a parquet file by groups

Tags: python, python-polars, pyarrow

I have a large-ish dataframe in a Parquet file and I want to split it into multiple files to leverage Hive partitioning with pyarrow.
Preferably without loading all data into memory.

(This question has been asked before, but I have not found a solution that is both fast and with low memory consumption.)

As a small example consider the following dataframe:

```py
import polars as pl
from random import choice, randint
from string import ascii_letters

N = 10_000_000
pl.DataFrame({
    'id': [choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(N)],
    'a': [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(N)],
}).write_parquet('stackoverflow.parquet')
```

I know that pyarrow can help out, but it's super slow for big files.

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

ds_df = ds.dataset('stackoverflow.parquet')
ds.write_dataset(ds_df, 'stackoverflow_data', format='parquet', partitioning=['id'])
```

Polars can also help out, but the fastest solution I have made only works if I have the dataframe in memory:

```py
import os
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_parquet('stackoverflow.parquet')
split_df = df.partition_by('id', as_dict=True)
for id in split_df:
    save_path = os.path.join('stackoverflow_data', f'id={id}')
    os.makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)
    split_df[id].write_parquet(os.path.join(save_path, 'data.parquet'))
```

However, for large files I prefer to work with `LazyFrame`s.
This can be done by repeatedly filtering a `LazyFrame` and writing the result to disk:

```py
df_query = pl.scan_parquet('stackoverflow.parquet')
ids = df_query.select(pl.col('id').unique()).collect().get_column('id').to_list()
for id in ids:
    save_path = os.path.join('stackoverflow_data', f'id={id}')
    os.makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)
    df = df_query.filter(pl.col('id') == id).collect()
    df.write_parquet(os.path.join(save_path, 'data.parquet'))
```

Unfortunately, this is much slower due to the repeated filtering.

Any suggestions for a better tradeoff between speed and memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never going to do better than the approach where all your data is in memory. If it fits in memory then it's unclear what you would define as a better speed/memory tradeoff. Typically you only trade away speed for memory savings if you can't fit your data in memory. Incidentally though, when you say:

> Unfortunately, this is much slower due to the repeated filtering.

this isn't quite right. It's slower because of the repeated IO to the physical disk. If the file doesn't have multiple row groups with statistics then it has to scan the whole file at each pass.

My benchmarks are that the `partition_by` approach takes 5.8s.

The native `write_dataset` approach takes 6.9s.

The `scan_parquet` approach is 88.1s which is about half what 26x the first approach. Given that there are 26 ids that isn't too surprising.

The reason that the pyarrow `write_dataset` is so close to the optimal is that it will try to open all the final destination files at once so that as it reads data it writes it to where it will ultimately go. In that way it doesn't reread the data like in your `scan_parquet` approach.

If you had saved the initial file with row groups separated by id and with statistics then your last approach would have been much faster (although still not as fast as the native dataset approach). The initialization would like something like this:

```
df=pl.DataFrame({
    'id': [choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(N)],
    'a': [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(N)],
})
ids=df.get_column('id').unique()
saveschema=df.to_arrow().schema
with pq.ParquetWriter("stackoverflow2.parquet", 
                    saveschema,
                    compression='ZSTD',
                    version="2.6", ) as writer:
    for id in ids:
        writer.write_table(df.filter(pl.col('id')==id).to_arrow())
```

using the `ParquetWriter` with the for loop will create a row group each time `write_table` is called. Since pyarrow has statistics on by default (polars has them off by default) we don't have to specify this. The stats include min and max for each group. Since there is only one id per group the min and max will each be that id. In subsequent scans, the reader can tell from the stats which row groups it needs to read. In this way it can massively save on IO relative to having the ids placed randomly amongst all row groups because it only reads the relevant row group.

Using this file, which is partitioned internally by row groups, will massively improve the `scan_parquet` approach to just 7.5s.

Of course, this only helps you if you can change your upstream file creation but it is illustrative of what you're facing.

[More reading here](https://cloudsqale.com/2020/05/29/how-parquet-files-are-written-row-groups-pages-required-memory-and-flush-operations/)

Answer (score 1):

A 2-pass method which partitions by batch can improve performance (memory and speed) by an order of magnitude.

```py
ds_df = ds.dataset('stackoverflow.parquet')
for index, batch in enumerate(ds_df.to_batches()):
    ds.write_dataset(batch, f'temp/batch={index}', format='parquet', partitioning=['id'], partitioning_flavor='hive')
ds.write_dataset(ds.dataset('temp', partitioning='hive', schema=ds_df.schema), 'stackoverflow_data', format='parquet', partitioning=['id'])
```

The first pass partitions by `(batch, id)` without loading the entire table, using hive format for convenience. Then the second pass can take advantage of already being partitioned by `id`.

Comment: This looks nifty! However, I get an error in the last line b/c the Parquet files are not valid: `Could not open Parquet input source 'temp/batch=0/id=C/part-0.parquet': Couldn't deserialize thrift: TProtocolException: Invalid data`. 
Trying to load with Polars' `read_parquet` I get `ExternalFormat("File out of specification: Invalid thrift: end of file")`

Comment: Are you using a case-insensitive filesystem (the default on macOS)? I tested your example, but had to change the ids to lowercase to not have collisions.

Comment: Well spotted! I just tried it on Linux and then your code works out of the box. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76735331/fastest-and-canonical-way-to-write-dataframes-to-disk-by-group).

I was able to take inspiration from your looped `LazyFrame` approach and parallelize the loop using `spawn` [multiprocessing with polars](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/misc/multiprocessing/#pros-and-cons-of-fork). This gave me between a 5 and 10x speed up. It looks something like this.

```
df_query = pl.scan_parquet('stackoverflow.parquet')
ids = df_query.select(pl.col('id').unique()).collect().get_column('id').to_list()
def write_split_df(id):
    df = df_query.filter(pl.col('id') == id).collect()
    df.write_parquet(f'{id}.parquet')
def main():
    import multiprocessing as mp
    mp = mp.get_context('spawn')
    with mp.Pool(10) as p:
        p.imap_unordered(write_split_df, ids)
```

Comment: There is an open pull request to enable pyarrow's partitioned dataset writer: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/9835

Comment: This looks promising! Seems annoying that without legacy_dataset you get very little control over the filenames/file-structure generated. But better than nothing!