# Fastest and Canonical way to write dataframes to disk by group

Tags: python-polars

I have a workflow where I process and clean data from different sources and drop them into many folders where each folder contains the data for a single input to the model. So if I had 3 sources of data Source A, B, and C and 1000 datapoints my folder structure would have many folders named 1-1000 with each folder containing a.parquet, b.parquet, and c.parquet . Each of a.parquet, b.parquet, and c.parquet would be rows from the large tables that pertain to each individual datapoint.

The problem I have is that I can't find a efficient way to take a large dataframe A and "apply" a `write_parquet` operation by group.

The spirit of what I am trying to do is captured by the below code. But this is obviously pretty slow and unparallelized.

```py
for name, gdf in A.groupby(["datapoint_id"])):
    gdf.write_parquet(f"{name}/a.parquet")
```

This should be an embarrassingly parallelizable operation right? Anyone have tips on how I can get this to happen in good performance?

The above method results in ~25it/s which translates to splitting up dataframes with ~200k groups taking multiple hours. Monitoring my CPU util, it is probably only using ~25% of my total compute.

Discussion moved to similar question here: [Split a parquet file by groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649120/split-a-parquet-file-by-groups)

Comment: You're likely IO bound not CPU bound so working in parallel isn't going to help much. You could try pyarrow write dataset though. It's purpose built to write lots of files

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb but writing the whole dataset to one file is quite fast. Is the tax on IO much different with a bunch of small files vs one large one?

Comment: I asked the same question recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649120/split-a-parquet-file-by-groups

Comment: I found a palatable answer. Posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76766828/13307302