# Reading sorted parquet files and merge them with Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, memory, python-polars

In order to save memory, I have written 49 sorted files to disk:

```py
tissue_pq_paths = []

for tissue in tissues:
    [...]
    aggregated_tissue_df = [...].sort(groupby).collect()
    aggregated_tissue_df.write_parquet(tissue_pq_path, compression="snappy", statistics=True, use_pyarrow=True)
    tissue_pq_paths.append(tissue_pq_path)
    
    del aggregated_tissue_df
```

Now I want to read those 49 sorted files and merge them:

```py
(
    pl.scan_parquet(tissue_pq_paths, hive_partitioning=False)
    .sort(groupby)
    .sink_parquet(output_pq_file, compression="snappy", statistics=True)
)
```

My assumption was, since the individual files are already sorted, that polars would just merge the files without sort.
Instead, polars reads all files to memory and sorts them again globally.

What can I do about this issue?

Comment: It seems that parquet statistics don't include whether or not the column is sorted. You could try something like `pl.concat([pl.scan_parquet(x).set_sorted(groupby) for x in tissue_pq_paths])` but I'm not sure if that actually makes it better. As an aside, you can skip the step of writing a bunch of files and write to a single file from the beginning with `pq.ParquetWriter` [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649120/split-a-parquet-file-by-groups/76654876#76654876)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dean! Indeed, it turns out that polars, as of today, only remembers whether single columns are sorted, not multiple. Workarounds with creating an index column from the columns to sort do not work because sorting struct-type columns is not implemented yet. 
However, your suggestion with writing continuously to a single parquet file is very helpful. I can reorder my query s.t. it processes the input in batches and keeps the correct sort order without running OOM. Thanks a lot!